# Program for Dirac Matrix Traces

Tags: resource-recommendations, software, dirac-matrices

I want to calculate traces of Dirac matrices with a program like Mathematica. I found the package [FeynCalc](http://feyncalc.github.io/) or [Tracer.m](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/2987/) but they seem to be outdated.

Are there any better / newer solutions to this? I am also open to other Software than Mathematica.

Comment: First of all, FeynCalc is actively developed. Second, Tracer, although not actively developed, is still very much used in the HEP community because it provides a stable implementation of the Dirac algebra in the Breitenlohner-Maison-t'Hooft-Veltman scheme. Third, FORM as suggested by Suzu Hirose is of course a good choice, but the learning curve is much steeper than that of Mathematica. Finally, GiNaC and sympy also can compute traces, if you are more comfortable with C++ or Python. But at the end, in terms of performance FORM is the fastest thing on the market.

Comment: I've removed a couple of comments which were more like answers, but which didn't meet the resource-recommendation guidelines mentioned in the question banner.

Comment: @vsht have looked into [HEPMath](http://hepmath.hepforge.org)?  How about [Package-X](https://packagex.hepforge.org)

Comment: AFAIK HEPMath is not actively developed anymore, since the author left academia. Package-X is closed source, so I cannot say much about the algorithms used.  Still, it is definitely not faster on traces than FORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FORM](https://github.com/vermaseren/form) is a well-known system for these calculations. There is a [Wikipedia page about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FORM_(symbolic_manipulation_system)).